# React-Select how to handle default value without overriding selected value?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I have a form that I want to prefill with values if exists, but when I use it like below with React-Select it won't select the options on select

```
value={rowData?.components ? getOptions(rowData.components, components, 'name') : []}
```

Obviously, this is the problematic part `: []`.

I've also tried `: null` but it doesn't help.

When I tried this it just didn't render the default values:

```
rowData?.components && getOptions(rowData.components, components, 'name')
```

How can I work around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I've used `defaultValue` instead:

```
defaultValue={rowData?.components ? getOptions(rowData.components, components, 'name') : []}
```

so it doesn't override the `default` field, but still provides what I needed. for some reason it didn't work before, but after I've updated React-Select it worked fine.

Answer (score -1):

```js
class Selector extends Component {

  constructor(){
  super(props);
  
  this.state={
    selectedValue:''
  }
  
  }
  
  componentDidMount(){
  
  /*
  
  fetch the value and assign to state
  
  */
  
  this.setState({selectedValue:fetchedValue})
  
  }
  
  render(
  
  
  return(
  
  <ReactSelect value={this.state.selectedValue} onChange={()=>this.setState({selectedValue:option})} />
  )
  )

}
```

The problem happening is you are fixing the value if already present and that value is not updating so a better option can be to store the value in a state and then onChange change the value of the checkbox.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).